# Scalatra Swagger UI Unable To Map $ref For Nested Model

Tags: json, scala, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, scalatra

I created the JSON Schema path on my localhost. Copied the Swagger-UI module. Added the url in the Swagger-UI. I am getting this error that model not found. This is very strange because the JSON has all the models associated to the JSON Schema.

Why does it try to look for something like:

http://localhost:8080/OpenClaimRequest rather looking into the definitions in JSON itself?

[image]

JS Console Error Log

[image]

Comment: Can you post your Swagger spec (.json / .yaml file)?

Answer (score 0):

I was using Swagger-UI `3.x` version where as my `API spec` version was `1.2`

`API Spec 1.2` is compatible with `Swagger-UI 2.x` not any version higher than that.